# Shell script not exiting while loop

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Ive been messing with this for a long while and I just do NOT understand whats happening here. I need to take an input that varies in size, and append spaces to the line until the total character length is 82 long. The length is far going beyond 82, and I even tried adding if checks inside the while loop to try to break out but that didnt work. What am I doing wrong here?

```
dynamicline=$initial_string                           
echo $initial_string > dynamicline.txt           
dynamiclength=$( cat dynamicline.txt | wc -m )
cat dynamicline.txt | wc -m  #debugging purposes
dynamicoutput=$( cat dynamicline.txt )

while [ $dynamiclength -lt "82" ]
do  
    sed -i 's/$/ /' dynamicline.txt
    #adds an extra space to the dynamic line
    cat dynamicline.txt | wc -m  #debugging purposes
done
```

Comment: Your `while`  loop runs until `$dynamiclength` is >= 82. The issue is, you only calculate `$dynamiclength` and single time and never update the variable. Update the variable inside of the loop.

Comment: isn't easier with ```printf```? ```printf "[%-*s]" '10' '12345'```

Comment: why all the machinations with a file when you could add spaces on the end of the `dynamicline` variable while `"${#dynamicline}" -lt 82`?; as for why the loop never ends ... @jordanm is spot on ... `$dynamiclength` is never re-calculated during the loop so the test never changes (and the looping process just runs and runs and runs and runs ...)

Comment: Thanks, I dont know why but I thought every time it checked $dynamiclength it would do so by running cat dynamicline.txt | wc -m

Comment: @m004yu : Why do you think your variable would magically change its value just because you run some unrelated command? The variable holds - as every variable in bash - just a string. You can not bind a command to a variable.